# Explain typedef for function used in qsort library

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers, typedef, qsort

I am using qsort library function to sort an array of structure elements, while searching on the Internet I found a resource: [INFO: Sorting Structures with the C qsort() Function](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/73853) @ support.microsoft.

I understand that qsort function requires to be typecast by generic pointers.

However I am not able to get this line:

```
typedef int (*compfn) (const void*, const void*);
```

Which has been declared, and its subsequent call:

```
qsort((void *) &array,              // Beginning address of array
      10,                           // Number of elements in array
      sizeof(struct animal),        // Size of each element
      (compfn)compare               // Pointer to compare function
 );
```

1. How is `typedef` behaving, I mean what exactly have we typedeffed  `int (*compfn)` or `int (compfn)`?
2. If the former, then shouldn't the call be `(*compfn)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Syntax:**

```
typedef  int (*compfn)  (const void*, const void*);
  ^      ^       ^            ^          ^
  | return type  |               arguments type
  |             new type name 
  defining new type
```

`compfn` is a new user defined *`type`* defined by `typedef` keyword,

So, you have exactly typedefded  `int (*)(const void*, const void*);` to `comfn` using the syntax I described above.

**A declaration:**

```
 compfn  fun; // same as: int (*fun)  (const void*, const void*);
```

means `fun` is a function pointer that takes two arguments of `const void*` types and returns `int`.

Suppose you have a function like:

```
int xyz  (const void*, const void*);
```

then you can assign `xyz` address to `fun`.

```
fun = &xyz;
```

**At calling `qsort()`:**

In expression `(compfn)compare`, you are typecasting a function `compare` to `(compfn)` type function.

**A doubt:**

> shouldn't the call be `(*compfn)`.

No, its type name not function name.

**Note**: if you just writing `int (*compfn)  (const void*, const void*);` without typedef then `comfn` will be a pointer to a function that returns `int` and take two arguments of type `const void*`

Comment: Thanks! But,please explain this  code "typedef int (*compfn)" as well .What exactly have we "typedeffed", int (*compfn) or int (compfn).

Comment: @DrefD `typedef int (*compfn)` is not correct, `typedeffed` also error . `int (*compfn) ` should be `int *compfn`

Comment: @DrefD got your confusion now, see what I describe in syntax of define a `new type`, a type for function. What partial things you are asking about is not valid.

Comment: @DrefD you have exactly typedefded   `int (*)(const void*, const void*);` to `comfn` useing the syntax I described above.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, please see http://ideone.com/6XqTrN  in response to "int (*compfn) should be int *compfn". I guess the latter isn't correct, PS: your last note clears some of my doubt!

Comment: Is what I am thinking correct? According to: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7042/How-to-interpret-complex-C-C-declarations and GrijeshChauhan,  we have "typedeffed" the entire expression to compfn, thus compfn in itself refers to   int ( * )(const void*, const void*);

Comment: @DrefD I saw the link-1 of ideone I didn't find any `"int (*compfn)`

Answer (score 3):

The `typedef` declaration creates an *alias* for a specific type. This means it can be used as any other type in declarations and definitions.

So if you have e.g.

```
typedef int (*compfn)(const void*, const void*);
```

Then you can declare a variable or argument using only `compfn` instead of the whole function pointer declaration. E.g. these two declarations are equal:

```
compfn function_pointer_1;
int (*function_pointer_2)(const void*, const void*);
```

Both creates a function pointer variable, and the only difference is the name of the variable name.

Using `typedef` is common when you have long and/or complicated declarations, to easy both your writing of such declarations and to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

It is a type of a function pointer. The function which is being pointed to returns `int` and accepts two `const void*` parameters.