# Two pointer related questions

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

I am looking to understand the following two pieces of code. I am not proficient in C++ and pointers and the operations which can be used with them are still a little unclear to me.

## First piece of code

I have trouble understanding what this function actually does. It takes an unsigned char pointer and returns one as well. But the way I currently see it, it just returns a pointer that points to the same place as the original. I might *very well* be wrong though.

```
unsigned char* MemoryPool::GetNext(unsigned char* pBlock)
{
    unsigned char** ppChunkHeader = (unsigned char**)pBlock;
    return ppChunkHeader[0];
}
```

**Edit:** I made an attempt at improving the quality of my formatting and clarifying my problems. I appreciate your helpful comments and answers.

## Second piece of code

I know that this is a typedef that *aliases* (would that be a correct term?) a function pointer as under the type name ActorComponent. But what does the function pointer's function type return? If function pointer syntax is:

```
void (*foo)(int);
```

Then what is the meaning of the asterisk before the parentheses in the following line of code?

```
typedef ActorComponent *(*ActorComponentCreator)(void);
```

Comment: "the source code of the book from which the code is from has changed to something else:" - what? The source code of the book has changed? And what's all with that "mistake"? What mistake?

Comment: In **Second** you are defining new usefedined type : [`ActorComponentCreator` is a new user defined type defined by typedef keyword that is function  pointer type, accepts no arguments and returns ActorComponent`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17782679/please-explain-typedef-for-function-while-using-qsort-library/17782725#17782725) read today I answered. Whereas **First** is `ppChunkHeader[0]` == `*(ppChunkHeader + 0)`  == `*ppChunkHeader` == `pBlock`

Comment: I'm sorry I meant that I downloaded the (updated) source code from the book authors' website. The code in the book is what I have presented above.

Comment: seems like it is casting pBlock into unsigned char array pointer then returning the first element of the array. Something like that

Comment: The part I don't understand is the *(*type)(void); syntax. I realize it is a function pointer but what does the extra asterisk mean?

Comment: 1) type punning of a particularly ugly (and likely a little on the unsafe side) sort, and 2) pointer to function that returns a pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first code is given an `unsigned char *` (treating approximately as if it was a `void *`; is the code very old, or based on very old software), converts it to a pointer to a pointer to an `unsigned char`, and then returns the zeroth `unsigned char *`.  So, it treats the location it is passed as if it was the start of an array of `unsigned char *` values, and returns the zeroth item in that array.  In C++, this is not very good code; it would be more respectable as C code.

The second code declares a pointer to function type named `ActorComponentCreator`.  The function returns an `ActorComponent *`; the function takes no arguments.

Comment: I'm unsure of the code's age but I know the author of it has been programming for many years so it might be a personal thing he has not gotten rid of.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like the first one doesn't do much. It casts the passed in pointer to unsigned char to be a pointer to pointer to char (a dangerous and old c style cast at that). Then it uses the fact that an array dereference acts like a pointer dereference to return the original pointer to an unsigned char.

```
typedef ActorComponent *(*ActorComponentCreator)(void);
```

Creates a function pointer. In this case ActorComponentCreator is the name that refers to a pointer to a function that takes a void and returns a pointer to an ActorComponent.

Comment: Am I confused? That isn't how I read it. I don't believe it is actually the original pointer that's being returned. Rather, I think the char that was pointed to in the argument is itself being re-interpreted as a pointer, and then returned. I think an equivalent statement would be: return (unsigned char*) (*pBlock);

Comment: @csj You're sorta right - it's re-interpreting the first several (probably 4 or 8, depending on whether it's 32-bit or 64-bit) `char`s pointed to as a pointer, and returning that. Your `return (unsigned char *)(*pBlock)` would not be equivalent, because that only reinterprets the single character at `pBlock` as a pointer.

Comment: @twalberg Doh! That's right. Thank you. Despite my faulty alternaive code, my core point stands, however. The pointer returned is NOT the same as the pointer provided.

Answer (score 2):

If we look at this:

```
typedef ActorComponent *(*ActorComponentCreator)(void);
```

and change it around a little:

```
typedef ActorComponent* (*ActorComponentCreator)(void);
```

it becoems much clearer that it's a function pointer  to a function that returns a pointer to an `ActorComponent`.

Compare with:

```
typedef int* (*FuncReturningInt)(void);
```