# invalid conversion from void* to void(*)(void*)[-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, c, pointers, function-pointers

this question was asked in relation to threads, but I have a simpler case.(beginner)
I tried the code in different compilers for c++ but would not work.
please advise how to replace the line:   `callback = (void*)myfunc;` //--> `error`

```
typedef struct _MyMsg {
        int appId;
        char msgbody[32];
} MyMsg;    
void myfunc(MyMsg *msg)
{
        if (strlen(msg->msgbody) > 0 )
                printf("App Id = %d \n Msg = %s \n",msg->appId, msg->msgbody);
        else
                printf("App Id = %d \n Msg = No Msg\n",msg->appId);
}    
/*
 * Prototype declaration
 */
void (*callback)(void *);    
int main(void)
{
        MyMsg msg1;
        msg1.appId = 100;
        strcpy(msg1.msgbody, "This is a test\n");    
        /*
         * Assign the address of the function 'myfunc' to the function
         * pointer 'callback'
         */                 
//line throws error: invalid conversion from void* to void(*)(void*)[-fpermissive]    
        callback = (void*)myfunc; //--> error               
        /*
         * Call the function
         */
        callback((MyMsg*)&msg1);    
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you compiling this as C++ - it looks like vanilla C ?

Comment: You don't need the cast in `callback((MyMsg*)&msg1);` since `&msg1` is *already* a `MyMsg*`.

Comment: It is actually invalid to cast a function pointer to a void *

Answer (score 4):

Yes, your  typecasting is wrong:

```
 callback = (void*)myfunc;
              ^
               is void*  but Not void (*)(void*)
```

You can do like:

1. Define a new type:

   ```
   typedef  void (*functiontype)  ( void*);
   ```
2. Typecast as follows:

   ```
   callback = (functiontype)myfunc;
   ```

Comment: Read [Explain typedef for function used in qsort library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17782679/explain-typedef-for-function-used-in-qsort-library)

Comment: The point is that this kind of cast should be avoided in first place; instead, he should correct his function signature to match the prototype of the function pointer and avoid the cast altogether.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Yes you are perfectly correct. I just shown how to resolve error. And I notice @ ChrisDodd given a very nice answer.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `callback` is not a void pointer, its a pointer to a function.  So to shut up the warning, you need to cast to the correct type:

```
callback = (void (*)(void *))myfunc;
```

Note that this will get rid of the warning, but is not guaranteed to work -- while you can cast a function pointer type to a different function pointer type, calling the resulting function pointer (without first casting it back) is Undefined Behavior.

Now on *most* machines, all pointers have the same internal bit representation.  In particular, `MyMsg *` and `void *` will be the same, so this will in fact work fine.  But its not guaranteed.  To be strictly standards conforming, you should change `myfunc` to be:

```
void myfunc(void *msg_)
{
    MyMsg *msg = (MyMsg *)msg_;
    :
```

Now it has the same signature as `callback`, so you can assign it without casting. The cast inside `myfunc` is probably a noop, but needs to be there for strict conformance.

Comment: +1 for the warnings about this kind of casts; in general, [if you have to cast you can't afford it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/10/23/9911891.aspx), especially because trying to shut up the compiler with casts often results in hiding serious bugs.